# How can I add superscript character in a textfield

Tags: 7, entities

I am looking for a way to use superscript characters in a Drupal textfield. When I copy and paste from a Word document, Drupal changes it to plain text.

Expected Result: **m<sup>2</sup>**

Actual Result: **m2**

What’s the correct way to use the superscript in fields? How can I enable special character support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for me. Instead of using a feature WYSIWYG, which make it kind of confusing on endless fields, I’ve decided to use [Unicode superscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts).

Answer (score 0):

On a vanilla drupal 7 site you can set the text format of the field to full HTML and use standard HTML to render the superscript.

For the paste from word functionality, I would recommend adding the WYSIWYG module and following the instructions to get a proper editor like ckeditor. Will be a world of difference.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. ckeditor was my second choice.  I’d like to keep it simple without installing Ckeditor. It’s just a single line textfield with plain text. A full feature WYSIWYG is not required here. I’ve ended up using unicode superscripts.